# Improve tesseract results (pytesseract)

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract

I have been downloading tiles from a [TMS-like](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/TMS) server displaying some "google tiles" with geodatas. Those datas are french townships, set in some particular colors regarding to the map's legend.

I have written an algorithm which mainly uses PIL to process tiles (as pictures) before presenting those to tesseract (using pytesseract). In the end, knowing the tile's position (and therfore knowing which townships may be in the area), I use fuzzywuzzy process.extractBests to try to identify which township has been found.

So far, some pictures which don't handle any result from tesseract seem relatively fine to me *(though it is not perfect, you can distincly read the french name "Sainte Honorine de Ducy")* :
[image: one example of tile failed to be read correctly by tesseract]

I should precise that in this case, the original tile is around 1500x3000 pixels (I have already been extending the tile's size).

I have also modified pytesseract to pass the 'bazaar' keyword which was mentionned in the doc plus custom 'user-words' containing townships from the area. That beeing said, I could only find "bazaar" reference in [tesseract 1 documentation](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/master/doc/tesseract.1.asc), without anything better than a link in newest documentations. In fact, I seem to remember a post somewhere about it beeing a mistake in documentation... For what it's worth, it doesn't seem to change the results here.

Do you have any suggestions ? In particular, do you think the picture's quality would be considered good enough to expect solid results ?

I know almost nothing about training tesseract on my own with these particular font. Considering that (and that I don't manage the datasource, that I don't even know what font is used...), I hope that you may have better suggestions than taking this (huge) leap...

PS : I know I maybe shouldn't have posted this question whithout any code, but I'm more in a need for global guidance here... I will post any recquired code anyway !

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that the text is too small compared to the image size.

You should apply some more image transformations to find a more exact area where the text is located, try something as [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html) and then [find the contours](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html) of the area with the text. Take a look also as [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/) tutorial, it's with OpenCV.

I tried to crop the image with GIMP and then resized it to make a little bigger:

[image]

The result with pytesseract is:

```
Saiptnmnorine-de-Ducy
```

that is acceptable, with some other processings with fuzzywuzzy you could get the right name.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try this evening. Though what you thought was an acceptable result may depend of the area... (Thanks to french history, we may have (very) close-named townships as neighbours. I used to live around two villages called 'Cerny-les-Bucy' and 'Bucy-les-Cerny' : this can still be tricky for fuzzywuzzy and I had to set a very high score cutoff for now...)

Comment: Could you confirm me the size/format of the picture + tesseract's version ? Event after resampling the picture, I only got disapointing results (_'SaipneJ-tonorineodeoucy'_, _'Saipæ+ﬁonoñne—de0ucy'_, _'Saipmﬂonorinedemcy'_ or _'&ipæHonoñne—de0ucy'_, depending of the picture's size and the language setting : fra of default).

Comment: The image is 500x93. I have Tesseract 3.05.00. Have you tried with `--psm 7` (single text line) or `--psm 8` (single word)?

Comment: Uh, never mind... It seems I resized it a bit too big : once I reduced the resizing ratio, tesseract handled it better. It is a bit unexpected though, as for some other townships, I get perfect results handling the same level of zoom... I'll give it a try with various pictures and let you know.

Comment: Sorry, that could take some time : those datas include meteorological datas (raining datas that is, and it is currently sunny in whole France...)